# How do I replace a Null with a Blank Space in KDB?

Tags: null, kdb

In KDB I can replace a Null with a 0 using the ^ however this won't work with text.  Does anybody know how to do this?  Thanks.

```
a:0n

0^a
0

`a^a
ERROR: 'type 
(wrong type)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace null characters within a string using the same fill function:

Note: null char is " "

```
q)"_"^"Spaces are nulls"
"Spaces_are_nulls"
```

For symbols:

````
q)`n^`list```of``symbols```with`nulls
`list`n`n`of`n`symbols`n`n`with`nulls
````

In your example it looks like you want to replace null floats with a symbol.
The type mixing makes this more complex. The following works:

```
q)a:0n
q)anyTypeFill:{$[null y;x;y]}
q)anyTypeFill[`a;a]
`a
q)anyTypeFill[`a;] each 0n 1 2 0n 3 5 0n
`a
1f
2f
`a
3f
5f
`a
```